# Bicep add parameters to Automation Account Job Schedule

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-automation, azure-bicep

Bumping up against Bicep documentation as usual. I can't seem to find any help on how to add parameters to a Job Schedule for an Automation Account Runbook.

Example from MS is

```
  name: 'string'
  parent: resourceSymbolicName
  properties: {
    parameters: {}
    runbook: {
      name: 'string'
    }
    runOn: 'string'
    schedule: {
      name: 'string'
    }
  }
}
```

But when i try -

```
parameters:{
Param1: 'myval'
Param2: 'myval2'
}
```

It doesnt get added to the job schedule at all. It's also frustrating that they don't have a JSON view of the Job Schedule section so you can click-ops it and add parameters and then check the file to see the structure. Anyone come across this?

Comment: have you try the export template option on azure portal ? it should show you the generated arm. you can also use az cli to call the arm api directly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-rest-examples

Comment: The Export Template option on the automation account or the runbook doesnt include the Schedule for some reason.

Comment: can you try `Param1: '"myval"'` ? Also which api version are you using ?

Comment: That looks better, but stuck on how to assign a variable to the param - like param1: variables.subid

Comment: Is it a bicep variable ? parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it a try using api-version 2022-08-08 and I had to add extra `double quotes` for the parameter values:

```
parameters:{
  Param1: '"myval"'
  Param2: '"myval2"'
}
```